# Bootstrap 4 - How remove or edit opacity in modal.backdrop

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with angular and want to create a modal.
However I am having a lot of problems removing or editing modal-backdrop as it never takes my values ​​in css.

It is possible to remove through data-backdrop = false, I know, but I intend to close the modal when I click outside of this, it gives not use the data-backdrop.

Can someone experienced help me? I've been at this for days and so far still nothing.

I leave my code and stackblitz to test. Thanks !

**Code**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkdxna?file=src%2Findex.html)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here, I was able to change the background opacity and colour here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dh6k3

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Such a simple solution but not easy to find, thank you very much! I was always trying something with the .modal backdrop and nothing. Thanks! Make the answer, to give you the merit

Comment: I have added my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dh6k3

you can add

```
.fade.show {
  background: red; // example
  opacity: 1; // example
}
```

and you are able to edit the modal backdrop

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer without using `!important` (should be avoided when possible)

```
::ng-deep .modal-backdrop.show {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```